# Connecting probelm with ASUS router

Tags: networking, router, dns, home-networking, asuswrt-merlin

I am lived in Hng Kong, and I have an ASUS RT-AC68U router purchased , and with ASUSWRT-merlin installed, and using the 1.1.1.1 DNS. Within the last 2 years that is experiencing continually more confounding problems.

Situation

More and more frequently, the following conditions suddenly present themselves:

All the devices (No matter Microsoft Windows,Google Android or Apple iOS) are not being able to connect to all China-related and websites that are hosted in China. All the main domain (ie, baidu.com) works, but some CDNs (I guess) are not being able to connect. All browsers (Google Chrome, Mozilla Forefox Quantum or Apple safari), and all built in app wont load everything.

What I have tried

Unplugging and replugging the router (duh)

Factory-resetting the router and rebuilding all settings from scratch. The only things I changed from the default were the network name and password and the router's login credentials. This reset didn't seem to have an effect on the timing or nature of the issue.

Making sure the router's firmware is up to date.

Reflushing the DNS with ipconfig command on Microsoft Windows.

Connecting to a VPN.
Disconnecting all wireless and wired devices from the network then slowly adding them back one by one.

No particular device seems to trigger the problem.

I am hard-pressed to think of anything that changed with my home network that specifically correlates with the onset of this problem. Any tips or tricks are appreciated, and I'm happy to provide more information if necessary.

Also it seems the issue only happens to me (Maybe I am the only one in the world having this issue?)

Comment: When not being able to connect to all China-related websites what exactly happens? Have you tried to ping such a website's IP address? Have you tried to traceroute the packet to that website?

Comment: Well, some websites will able to connect (like baidu.com), but some wont. Like tieba.baidu.com

Comment: Also when tou connect theese websites from web proxies, it works, and rhe traceroute acts strange. I tried an online traceroute and do iton my router, it seems after outgoing from the isp, and there is no respond.

Comment: So you can visit Chinese website but can't visit google?  As I know, China blocked many external websites, such as facebook, google.

Comment: No, I am in Hong Kong, and I can't access Chinese websites, anyways the problem is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I need to do is go to the management interface - WAN - and click on get MAC address, and it works.